# Replacing list elements with numbers while retaining original names in R

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list in R named `Cell.Arrangement` that consists of 9 different cell arrangement types. I am attempting to replace these arrangements with the numbers 1-9 while for the purpose of fitting them through a neural network, but I need to keep an index of what the numbers correspond to so the output can be read.

The first few elements of the list like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Chains"  "Pairs"   "Singles"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] "Singles"

[[6]]
[1] "Tetrad"
```

...And the desired outcome is something like this...

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 4
```

...Where each cell arrangement classification corresponds to a number but can be matched back.

I have the following code, but it instead of replacing the arrangements with a unique number in the overall list, it replaces the arrangements with a unique number in each element, so different arrangements are matched with the same number...

```
RL_AR <- function(x){
  if(length(levels(factor(Data$Cell.Arrangement[[x]]))) > 0){ 
    as.vector(factor(Data$Cell.Arrangement[[x]], labels = c(1:length(Data$Cell.Arrangement[[x]]))))
  }else{
    as.vector(factor(Data$Cell.Arrangement[[x]], labels = ''))
  }
}

AR.Index <- data.frame(unique(unlist(Data$Cell.Arrangement)))
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like your list has names, so I'm not sure what you mean by "while retaining original names". Can you show the output you are looking for? Also sharing the your data with `dput()` is nice so it is copy/pasteable. Could you add `dput(head(your_list))` to your post?

Comment: Accidently submitted question. Has now been completed and the actual list is shown rather than dput()

Comment: Yes, could you please **add the `dput` to your question** to make it easier to reproduce?? And do you already have the lookup matching between cell arrangement classifications and numbers? Or is creating that what you mean by "retaining original names"?

Comment: Lastly, if you're converting all the strings to integers, are you sure you want `character(0)` rather than `integer(0)` or `numeric(0)` in the empty elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first make a vector of the unique arrangements, then use this vector, to change every character string to the corresponding number (position in the vector `arr`)

```
lst <- list(c("Chains",  "Pairs",   "Singles"),
     character(0),
     character(0),
     character(0),
     c("Singles"),
     c("Tetrad")
)

arr <- unique(unlist(lst))

lapply(lst, function(x) match(x,arr))
```